# Stripe: received unknown parameter: fingerprint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

In my tests I received error:

```
Failure/Error: stripeToken: stripe_helper.generate_card_token,
Stripe::InvalidRequestError:
   Received unknown parameter: fingerprint
```

This is my code:

```
let(:stripe_helper) { StripeMock.create_test_helper }
let(:payment_params) do
 { .., stripeToken: stripe_helper.generate_card_token }
end
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to mock this way. To generate_card_token you have to provide the params.

```
let(:stripe_helper) { StripeMock.create_test_helper }
let(:payment_params) do
   StripeMock.generate_card_token(last4: "2244", exp_month: 33, exp_year: 2255)
end
describe 'Token Creation' do
 it "generates and reads a card token for create charge" do
   charge = Stripe::Charge.create(amount: 500, currency: 'usd', source: payment_params)
   card = charge.source
   expect(card.last4).to eq("2244")
   expect(card.exp_month).to eq(33)
   expect(card.exp_year).to eq(2255)
 end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Mohammad Shahadat Hossain ;)